# Cant display recently added Razor Page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

When I try to add new page to the existing project it gets added to the solution explorer. But I cant display the new page.

Here's my solution explorer window:

[image]

But when im trying to reach https://localhost:44340/Home/Filter it displays (404 page not found):

[image]

And here's Configure function at Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                
            });
            //SeedIdentity.Seed(userManager, roleManager, Configuration).Wait();
        }
```

I can also reach Home/Index, Home/OperationDetail without any problems.

What am i missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Eren Temelli, does your HomeController contains action named `Filter`?

Comment: Hi @Rena, No its not. After adding action named Filter my problem is gone, thank you :)

Comment: The razor page's route is not as same as the MVC controller routes, the razor page's route will normally look up the page folder inside your solution, but the MVC controller route will firstly check the controller's name and action name to find the match route. More details about how it works, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).